# Credit Spread, Transition Matrix

Tags: transition-matrix

Consider a credit rating system consisting of three credit states, A, B and D (default)
with the following annual credit transition probability:
T = [0.7 0.2 0.1;0.2 0.5 0.3; 0 0 1].

For a company rated B, calculate:
a) The credit spread, calculated semi-annually, ten years into the future.

The semi-annually is throwing me off. I know that credit spread = - ln q where q is the solvency. For ten years into the future, we simply take T^10 and the solvency is just 1-default. But they want the credit spread calculated semiannually, ten years into the future.

Edit: I'm wondering if it's asking two different questions ie. calculate credit spread semiannually (T^1/2) and ten years into the future (T^10), or is there a way to calculate the semi annual rate ten years into the future?

Comment: [Related](http://quant.stackexchange.com/q/10624/56)

Comment: You need a matrix whose square is the annual matrix.  The question is covered at http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/10645/scaling-of-a-transition-matrix/10647#comment16857_10647

Comment: Awesome thank you. I finished the question, I'm just wondering now about the yield rate. Id use 1%/2 for the semiannual coupons, yes?